# How to pass a SortedSet as an Intent's extra?

Tags: android

I have a service that produces as result a `SortedSet` object. I need to pass it to another `Intent` that will use it. First is put in the notification area, then when the user actions it it will need to fire the activity.

As it it's own SortedSet is not `Parcelable` nor `Serializable` so it won't work. One single item in `SortedSet` is already parcelable and it's used fine, but I need the whole set.

How to pass a `SortedSet` as an Intent's extra?

Comment: Im looking for the same!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out:

```
// passes as serializable and as Array
intent.putExtra("results", result.toArray());
```

Then read out by reconstructing the array into the `SortedSet`.

In my case it was:

```
Serializable s = this.getIntent().getSerializableExtra("results");
Object[] o = (Object[]) s;
if (o != null) {
    resultSet = new TreeSet<RatedMessage>(new Comp());
    for (int i = 0; i < o.length; i++) {
        if (o[i] instanceof RatedMessage) {
            resultSet.add((RatedMessage) o[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Now I can use `resultSet` further.